# trying to create a Universal app for iOS Devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal-binary

I have my iPhone app ready and now i've to make it a Universal app.

I'm doing this..

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
self.appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window.frame = self.appFrame;
UINavigationController *aNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myViewController];
aNav.view.frame = self.appFrame; 
self.nav = aNav;
[self.window addSubview:nav.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I don't have `MainWindow.xib` in my project. I'm creating it programmatically.

So if i use this code to give the frame to the window

```
self.appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window.frame = self.appFrame;
```

Then it iPad should have `(0,0,768,1024)` and iPhone should have `(0,0,320,480)`

But, if I run my code on iPad simulator it takes `self.appFrame` as `(0,0,320,480)`

Can you guys explain me what's the problem??

and

How can i create a Universal app without using `MainWindow.xib`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Build Settings tab of your target in Xcode and set the **Targeted Device Family** key to **iPhone/iPad**. Then your app compiles as native iPad and iPhone application and `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` should return the correct results. Btw, you should use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` instead of bounds for the window frame!

Comment: actually `applicationFrame` gives height-20 pixels.. and i wanted the fullScreen size so i opted for `bounds`.

Comment: Anyways i tried it on the device directly and it worked. Thnks.. :)